# What is the probability of 4 out of 25 are intoxicated

Tags: probability

Q: According to an accurate survey, 40% of people checked at the exit of a well-known pub have made excessive use of alcoholic drinks. If we take a random sample of 25 persons, what is the probability that at least 4 of them are flagged?

Comment: are you familiar with the binomial distribution? In your title you say '$4$', in your question 'at least $4$'.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Comment: Depends on the date. And the pub. Any pub in Dublin, Ireland on St. Patrick's Day? 100%.

Answer (score 1):

We use the following model. We check, one after the other, $25$ people leaving the pub, and determine for each whether she is intoxicated. We assume that for any person, the probability of intoxication is $0.40$, and that the intoxication/sobriety of the various people are **independent** events. (This assumption is rather dubious.)

Under this model, the number $X$ of intoxicated people in a sample of $25$ has *binomial* distribution, and for any $k$, we have that the probability that $X$ is *exactly* $k$ is given by
$$\Pr(X=k)=\binom{25}{k}(0.4)^k (0.6)^{25-k}.\tag{1}$$

We want $\Pr(X\ge 4)$. Now use Formula (1). Unless you are using software, it will be substantially easier to calculate first the probability that $X\le 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Binomial Distrubituion, and sum for each possible value, since the question says that 4 or more could be flagged

$(nCr)p^k(1-p)^m$ where $m=n-k$

So this would be the probability that 4 are flagged, 5 are flagged and so on. Since there are many numbers, it would be much easier to express this as $1-P(3)-P(2)-P(1)-P(0)$. I have to run, so I can't write this whole thing out, so I'll just leave an example

For $P(3)$, we would write 25$C$3$(0.4)^3$$(0.6)^{22}$   $~$$~$

Repeat this for each of the other numbers, and subtract from 1.

Comment: That's supposed to be a 22 in that exponent. I don't know why it isn't working.